# How to find an object in std::vector?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class called Bank, with attributes

```
class Bank {
      string _name;
}
```

Now I declare a vector of Bank.

```
vector<Bank> list;
```

Given a string, how do I search the vector list for that particular Bank object that has the same string name?

I'm trying to avoid doing loops and see if there is an stl function that can do this.

Comment: [`std::find` or `std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). This is assuming that `Bank` has other members, but you only want to find on `_name`.

Comment: `vector` does not impose any ordering on the list, so searching it can only be done linearly.  There are STL containers that do order their contents, though.

Comment: Although `vector` does not impose ordering, ordering may be imposed on it. In this case, you can use other algorithms such as `std::binary_search` (only tests for the presence of the search item and returns a `bool`) or `std::equal_range` for O(log n) searches.

Comment: I don't have to bother about efficiency, but just want a compact code.

Comment: I doubt you want to use the STL.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What makes you say that?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Because it's outdated and not shipped with your toolchain. One should prefer the C++ Standard Library (even though the STL tracks it pretty closely nowadays).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use good old linear search:

```
auto it = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), [&](const Bank& bank)
{
    return bank._name == the_name_you_are_looking_for;
});
```

If there is no such bank in the list, the end iterator will be returned:

```
if (it == list.end())
{
    // no bank in the list with the name you were looking for :-(
}
else
{
    // *it is the first bank in the list with the name you were looking for :-)
}
```

If your compiler is from the stone ages, it won't understand lambdas and `auto`. Untested C++98 code:

```
struct NameFinder
{
    const std::string& captured_name;

    bool operator()(const Bank& bank) const
    {
        return bank.name == captured_name;
    }
};

NameFinder finder = {the_name_you_are_looking_for};
std::vector<Bank>::iterator it = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), finder);
```

Comment: Yet another syntactic sugar treat that allows to implement incredibly inefficient search without noticing, unless you're a template expert. "Leave the user free to shoot himself in the foot" philosophy", I suppose.

Comment: @kuroineko I have no idea what you're talking about. Are you complaining that linear search has linear complexity?

Comment: Never seen auto before. What does it do? I'm new to programming/c++.

Comment: @YellowSkies Since 2011, `auto` means "type inference" in C++. That is, the compiler will figure out the type of a variable based on the expression that is used to initialize it. In this case, the type of `it` is inferred to be `std::vector<Bank>::iterator`.

Comment: @YellowSkies: Note that in addition to `auto`, this also uses a lambda function. You'll need to compile C++11 enabled for both. There are pre-C++11 ways to do this if necessary.

Comment: where is the lambda function being used? [](const Bank& bank) ?

Comment: The lambda function is `[](const Bank& bank)
{
    return bank._name == the_name_you_are_looking_for;
}`

Comment: Can I get a quick crash course on what is a lambda function? No need for details.

Comment: @YellowSkies: Try reading something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/7627218/10077

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid using this lambda expression and yet get a short and sweet answer like the above? Haven't learnt that yet. the link lost me at functor.

Comment: @YellowSkies Sure, see my update. Note how much boilerplate code lambdas prevent.

Comment: @FredOverflow when it could be in log2(n), yes. What is the point in giving access to a standard feature that does no better than a vintage for loop, except enticing a newbie into implementing an inefficient data structure?

Comment: @kuroineko All I did was answer the OP's question. We don't have enough information about the use cases to decide what operations we should optimize for. If searching for a bank by name is the predominant operation, and the list rarely changes, then binary search on a sorted list would probably be the best idea.

Comment: @FredOverflow Yeah, leave the noob free to shoot himself in the foot, and don't waste any time warning him about using a potentially inappropriate data structure hidden behind the syntactic sugar. Pure C++ philosophy.

Comment: @kuroineko Feel free to provide an answer that discusses more efficient data structures. You'll have my upvote.

Comment: @kuroineko: You don't know what other data structure would be more efficient. It may well be that the OP's requirements simply mean that a linear search isn't that big of a deal or that other data structures can't be used. You can't know in advance that linear search *is* inappropriate.

Comment: @kuroineko There's no syntactic sugar. It's a function that performs linear search. There's another function that performs binary search. Neither is syntactic sugar. They're both functions and they use the same syntax that *every other function* uses. They have one key difference, though: the binary search function has special preconditions that linear search doesn't, and it hides those preconditions behind the "syntactic sugar". How's that for shooting yourself in the foot? And you are wrong. Linear search cannot run in logarithmic time. That's why it is called *linear* search.

Comment: @kuroineko: To use binary search, the data must first be sorted. Depending on collection size and frequency of search vs. modification, keeping the collection sorted to allow binary search can easily be an overall loss.

Answer (score 2):

As per popular request, just a side note to warn potential beginners attracted by this question in the future:

`std::find` is using a linear method, because the underlying object (a vector in that case) is not designed with search efficiency in mind.

Using a vector for data where search time is critical will possibly work, given the computing power available in your average PC, but could become slow quickly if the volume of data to handle grows.

If you need to search quickly, you have other containers (`std::set`, `std::map` and a few variants) that allows retrieval in logarithmic times.

You can even use hash tables for (near) instant access in containers like `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`, but the cost of other operations grows accordingly. It's all a matter of balance.

You can also sort the vector first and then perform a dichotomic search with std:: algorithms, like `binary_search` if you have a strict order or `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range` if you can only define a partial order on your elements.

Comment: Why not talk about `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` while you're at it? They allow constant time retrieval. That's much better than logarithmic time.

Comment: @Etienne Yep, I added them, though their use is quite far from what you would expect from an array. The main point was to warn newbies about the potential inefficiency of a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

[std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) will allow you to search through the vector in a variety of ways.